# How to configure IP based rate limit via azure app service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice

I have developed a .net web api.

I will be hosting it on azure app service. How to configure IP based rate limit via azure app service?

For example so that say upto 1000 requests per day can be made into the api from each IP address.

Comment: You could use [APIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-flexible-throttling)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot achieve it just with plain App service. You have to onboard your api to Azure API management and set throttling policies. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-flexible-throttling) you can find more information about that.

Comment: How about if you have Angular frontend hosted in Azure Appservices